# NSOpenPanel allows a file's selection on the first invocation but not the second possibly due to an inode change

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a java swing app that calls [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel?language=objc) two times. The first time, it allows a file to be selected. When NSOpenPanel's [Open] button is clicked, the app changes the file that was selected such that the file's inode changes.

When the app calls NSOpenPanel again, that file is not selectable. But if I navigate away from that folder and come back to it, then the changed file is now selectable.

Is this NSOpenPanel behavior defined or undefined?

Is there any way I can coax NSOpenPanel to refresh it's view of the former folder instead of indicating staleness?

It inherits [NSSavePanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel?language=objc) and the only attribute there that looked interesting was `validateVisibleColumns` but it isn't accessible to NSOpenPanel, according to my compiler.

Below is the MCV example that reliably repros what I consider a problem on Sonoma 14.2.1 and Xcode 15.2.

Open.java

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
public class Open extends JFrame {
   public Open () {
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
         public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void,Void>() {
                String[] files = null;
                public Void doInBackground () throws Exception {
                   files = NativeOpenFileDialog.run();
                   return null;
                }
                protected void done () {
                   if (files != null) {
                      for (String s : files) {
                         File old = new File(s);
                         File tmp = new File("tempfile");
                         try {
                            Files.copy(old.toPath(), tmp.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                            if (tmp.renameTo(old))
                               System.out.println(s + ": ok");
                            else
                               System.err.println(s + ": rename fail");
                         } catch (Throwable ex) {
                            System.err.println(s + ": copy fail");
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
         }
      }));
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() { new Open(); }
      });
   }
}
```

NativeOpenFileDialog.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class NativeOpenFileDialog {
   static {
       System.loadLibrary("natopndlg");
   };
   public static native String[] run ();
}
```

NativeOpenFileDialog.m

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#include <jni.h>
#include "NativeOpenFileDialog.h"

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_NativeOpenFileDialog_run (JNIEnv *env, jclass jcls) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        __block jobjectArray arr;
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            jclass strcls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
            NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
            [panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
            [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
            [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
            [panel setAllowsOtherFileTypes:YES];
            if ([panel runModal] != NSModalResponseOK) {
                arr = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 0, strcls, NULL);
                return;
            }
            NSArray *urls = [panel URLs];
            int count = urls == NULL ? 0 : [urls count];
            arr = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, count, strcls, NULL);
            if (urls != NULL) {
                int i = 0;
                for (NSURL* url in urls) {
                    NSString *path = [url path];
                    jstring str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, [path UTF8String]);
                    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, arr, i++, str);
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }
}
```

makefile

```
SDK = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk

Open.class: Open.java NativeOpenFileDialog.java NativeOpenFileDialog.m
    javac -h . NativeOpenFileDialog.java
    javac Open.java
    gcc -dynamiclib -o libnatopndlg.dylib -framework Cocoa -isysroot $(SDK) -I $(JAVA_HOME)/include -I $(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin -fobjc-exceptions -std=c99 NativeOpenFileDialog.m

clean:
    rm -f *.class *.dylib *.h
```

Compile, link, and go...

```
$ make
$ open Java
```

Click the app's button to open the open file dialog. Select any file and click [Open] to give that file a new inode. Click the app's button again and you'll see that the file previously selected is not selectable unless you navigate away from the folder and come back again.

Comment: What compiler error was there with -validateVisibleColumns ?  Any inherited method should exist.

Comment: Your answer is in my Edit 1.